# Alarm clock software that can turn the computer on?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, alarm

Is there any alarm clock software that can turn the computer on or wake it up from standby/hibernation, and play selected mp3 file at the required time?

E.g say I set an alarm for 7 am and turn off/hibernate/standby the computer. Is there any app that would wake up the computer automatically at 7 am and play the alarm?

I'm on windows xp but if any other OS has any such option, I'll be interested in hearing.

Comment: This can be done by any OS that supports ACPI, including Windows and Linux -- also called ["ACPI wakeup"](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup) or "RTC wakeup". I'm not aware of any Windows programs for this, though (but it can easily be scripted on Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of router do you have?  Reflash it with a Linux , and setup a crontab entry to send out the magic wake on LAN packet.  Configure computer to accept wake on lan.  Setup a scheduled task to play at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 1):

I use the windows task scheduler for this

it wakes up from standby without any issues, but hibernation is sometimes an issue

Tried with Windows Vista and 7

Comment: person who downvoted, mind telling why?

Answer (score 0):

This Winamp plugin can be used for sleep mode / alarm clock, but I don't know if it can turn your computer on for you if you have it turned off.

http://www.winamp.com/plugin/winampsleepalarm/138685

Comment: what does it do in terms of sleeping.. does it put the comp in standby?

Comment: This is probably not the ideal app for Sleep mode, as it has no configurable options.  Sleep Mode simply shuts  down Winamp after 60 minutes.  The Alarm function is pretty good, though.