# How do I create a wake up script using PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, unix, script, powershell, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alarm clock software that can turn the computer on?](https://superuser.com/questions/333456/alarm-clock-software-that-can-turn-the-computer-on)

I need something that can wake someone up in the morning - basically like a `cron` event in Linux. I think this needs to be done in PowerShell, and I don't know a thing about that. The requirements are:

1. It must wake up the computer from sleep at a specified time (eg. 07:00 hours).
2. It shall play a specified song in iTunes (or another program) at that time.

That's it! Answers that also feature a *NIX version of the script will be favored.

Comment: Why does it need to be a script? I used to do this, and I just used task scheduler to execute a playlist at the time I needed to get up. I even had the computer wake itself up to do it, then close WMP and put itself back to sleep after 10 minutes. Now I just use my phone.

Comment: What ^He^ Said.  Twice.

Comment: How about you slug your kid brother in the arm and tell him something to the effect of "grow up and figure out how to wake yourself up, dweeb!".  Or do older siblings not act like that anymore? :)

Comment: @SaintWacko The guy's name is (phonetically) "troll". I mean, c'mon now...

Comment: @techie007 Love it! Try the bucket-O-water alarm, gets them trained in just a few days.

Comment: @SaintWacko, it doesn't - I just assumed it did.

Comment: Like the alternative suggestions too - we'll give them a try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither you nor your kid brother need a PowerShell script. Therefore, I will not answer your question, but I will solve your problem.

Well, your kid brother not being able to wake up in the morning is almost certainly a problem I cannot solve. But I will try.

---

You can use **Task Scheduler** in Windows 7 to open an mp3 file in the default media player.

On the Windows 7 computer in question, open the Start menu and search for **Task Scheduler**. You will find a window that looks a lot like this:

[image: Task Scheduler]

On the **Action** menu, select **Create Basic Task...**.

[image: Create Basic Task Wizard: Create a Basic Task]

[image: Create Basic Task Wizard: Task Trigger]

[image: Create Basic Task Wizard: Daily]

[image: Create Basic Task Wizard: Action]

[image: Create Basic Task Wizard: Start a Program]

Choose to **Open the Properties dialog for this task when I click Finish**

[image: Create Basic Task Wizard: Summary]

Set the task to **Run whether user is logged on or not**

[image: General Tab]

Set **Wake the computer to run this task**

[image: Conditions Tab]

When you click **OK**, you will be prompted for the password of the user account that will run the task.

Answer (score -1):

Karen's Alarm Clock - I used it alot on late nightshifts when I needed heavy rock to wake me up in the evenings!

http://www.karenware.com/powertools/ptalarm.asp

not a powershell script, and haven't tested wake from sleep, but it gets the job done :)